# Data Explorer syntax or language reference?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Where can I find a syntax or language reference for the query language used on https://data.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: The language is T-SQL.

Comment: It's just [T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826(v=sql.90).aspx). Are you asking about something beyond that?

Comment: Beyond that, a reference for all the special stuff might be useful as well. There's parameters, links, the `site://` thing, magic columns and all that weird stuff. I think someone mentioned a graphing function once as well.

Comment: Here's the [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and Data Explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/) which can help. Also it has [a faq](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq) which includes some interesting tidbits on magic aliases and parameters

Comment: @Tim, that's the answer. I've never heard of TSQL. I was just trying to figure out how to write simple things like `select (*) from Users where LastAccessDate >= (Now - 90)` (active users in last 90 days), but have no idea what the correct function words are.

Comment: @lunboks Updated help documentation is forthcoming, I promise. :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) now has a [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) to get you started, the [help](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) states that SEDE runs on Microsoft SQL Server.

I've also created [this pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/109), as suggested by [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137175/data-explorer-syntax-or-language-reference#comment919512_234052), that will add on the [Next Steps](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/next-steps) page of the tutorial a reference to the Microsoft T-SQL language. That PR was deployed in revision  2020.12.13.80.

When creating a query the right side shows the tables and columns available. The functional details of the schema are described and updated here: [Database schema documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

The database is run on an instance of Microsoft Sql Server and therefor that sql dialect should be used, commonly known as [T-SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499(v=sql.110).aspx). The [current version](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201393/which-version-of-sqlsever-is-sede-using?opt.textResults=true#resultSets) is *Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU9) (KB5000642) - 15.0.4102.2 (X64)*.

Here is an [example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201403/demo-query?Score=4&UserId=14420) to get you going and that demonstrates the features for parameters and magic links as well:

```
-- Score: Score on the post "a number"
-- UserId: Your User id "That is the id in url on the site"
select u.id as [User Link]
     , p.id as [Post Link]
     , c.id as [Comment Link]
from comments c 
inner join posts p on p.id = c.postid
inner join users u on p.owneruserid = u.id
where c.userid = ##UserId##
and p.score > ##Score:int?2##
```

Or [this example that shows a nice graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201292#graph) (as seen in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260571/578411) by Shog9)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the SEDE tutorial doesn't actually say that the language is T-SQL, does it? That seems like vital information.

Comment: @DavidZ right, the help does, so I re-added that again.

Comment: @DavidZ oops, good catch.  We'll fix that when we next update the tutorial.